# Magento2 - is it possible to specify multiple urls in api?

Tags: magento2, api, url, routing

I would like to know is it possible to (call) specify multiple URLs in a single route **webapi.xml** ?

**Ex:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
        <route url="/V1/hello/test/" method="POST">
            <service class="Inchoo\Hello\Api\TestInterface" method="test"/>
            <resources>
                <resource ref="anonymous"/>
            </resources>
        </route>
    </routes>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can define the same API url name, BUT with different methods and actions:

```
    <route url="/V1/hello/test/" method="POST">
        <service class="Inchoo\Hello\Api\TestInterface" method="test"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>

    <route url="/V1/hello/test/" method="GET">
        <service class="Inchoo\Hello\Api\TestInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply please clarify can i mention any custom url in the route section or whether we need to follow certain rules?   like modulename , controllername, action....like that

Comment: It's hard to say, but we should try with sample: http://inchoo.net/magento/api-magento/magento-2-custom-api/ and https://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/

Comment: No problem i have followed the same url but i want to know thanks for giving valuable  info.